# Javascript convert string to be called as function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following scenario where I need to call a function based on the data attributes of the html element.

```
function func1(arg1){
    alert("func1");
}

function func2(arg2){
    alert("func2");
}

jQuery(document).on('click', '.func-class', function(){
  var funcName = jQuery(this).data('func-name');
  var funcArg = jQuery(this).data('func-arg');      
  //Need to call funcName(funcArg) here
});
```

HTML:

```
<div data-func-name="func1" data-func-arg="arg1" class="func-class">Func1</div>
<div data-func-name="func2" data-func-arg="arg2" class="func-class">Func2</div>
```

JSFiddle of the same:
http://jsfiddle.net/E4HeT/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If those functions are defined in ths global scope, you can do this:

```
window[funcName](funcArg);
```

Otherwise, I would suggest putting them in an object like so:

```
var functions = {
    "func1":func1,
    "func2":func2
};
functions[funcName](funcArg);
```

This second one is actually safer, as it helps prevent arbitrary code execution.

Answer (score 0):

you can do like the following [this](http://jsfiddle.net/E4HeT/1/)

```
window[funcName](funcArg)
```

but you will have to get the reference of the function by setting it in a object for example (like what i did in the window object) because its private in the jQuery.ready function

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.func-class').click(function(){

    var toCallArg = $(this).data('func-arg');        
    var toCall = function(toCallArg){            
        //your code
    };
    toCall(toCallArg);
});
```